# Can someone explain my code why it works?

Tags: javascript, html

The `drawImage()` function does not follow the function parameters to draw the image. The original dimension of the smiley is 213px (width) and 212px (height). The image was drew too big. The height of the drew image is 500px and the width of the drew image is about 400px (squeezed).

I have changed my code shown below. It works. The image will be drawn perfectly fine with the size 213x212. However, I cannot use the variables width and height as the actual parameters. i.e.

```
ctx.drawImage(smiley, sx, sy, swidth, sheight, x, y, width, height);
```

The image will not be drawn!! 
Now I can specify any dimensions e.g.

```
ctx.drawImage(smiley, sx, sy, swidth, sheight, x, y, 500, 500);
```

The image will be drawn perfectly fine with size 500x500.
I was wondering what exactly the statement

```
var width = c.setAttribute("width", "500");
```

does? I use debugger to check the variable width, it does not contain any value. hmmm...
If I delete the statement `var width = c.setAttribute("width", "500");`, the image will not be drawn at all!
Hope someone can explain it.

```js
var smiley = new Image();
smiley.src = "images/smiley.jpg";
window.onload = function () {
    var c = document.getElementById("mypic");
    var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
    var sx = 0;
    var sy = 0;
    var swidth = smiley.width;
    var sheight = smiley.height;
    var x = 0;
    var y = 0;

    //the following three lines are the original code
    //and is not working properly.
    //var width = smiley.width;
    //var height = smiley.height;
    //ctx.drawImage(smiley, sx, sy, swidth, sheight, x, y, width, height);      

    //Now, it is working fine        
    var width = c.setAttribute("width", "500");
    var height = c.setAttribute("height", "500");
    ctx.drawImage(smiley, sx, sy, swidth, sheight, x, y, 213, 212);
};
```

```css
canvas {
  background-color:green;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="mypic" ></canvas>
```

Comment: can you try `smiley.width` and `smiley.height` instead of height and width ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Few things to consider here:  First is its not `window.onload`, it should be the image object onload. Then you can set the canvas height and width based on the actual size of the image to be drawn. Here is a quick preview of it.

```js
var c = document.getElementById('canvas')
var ctx = c.getContext('2d')
var img = new Image();
img.src = 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e0/SNice.svg/220px-SNice.svg.png'

img.onload = function() {
  c.width = img.width;
  c.height = img.height;
  ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, img.width, img.height);
};
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" ></canvas>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! That is a great answer!

Comment: Happy to help! upvote and accept the answer if it helped. Thanks!